# How to lunch Java EE JavaFX application using appclient

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, glassfish, javafx

This is about Application Client Container.

I'm trying to develop a Java EE application using JavaFX. I've done it using Swing. I used GlassFish 3 appclient and it worked. Now I'm using JavaFX (javafx.runtime.version: 2.2.4-b19). It executes inside the Netbeans 7.2.1. But when I try to lunch my JavaFX version application using GlassFish Appclient it fails. These are my errors....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.ACCClassLoader.findClass(ACCClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.joy.azura.Freja.main(Freja.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.ACCClassLoader.findClass(ACCClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

Line 14 from top

```
at com.joy.azura.Freja.main(Freja.java:23)
```

This is my code

```
javafx.application.Application.launch(Mimir.class, args);
```

Mimir.class extends Application. It is where JavaFX starts.

I've also tried making the Main class extend Application so I can begin with JavaFX. It worked inside Netbeans not outside. Right now my Main class call Mimir class which wakes up the JavaFX.

I'm guessing since it can be executed inside Netbeans there is a way to do it outside. May be tweaking something...

Most of the solutions I've found in Google are old(2007-08). JavaFX script was different at the time.

Comment: Do you use maven? If so, please add your pom.xml to the question. It looks like a dependency problem.

Comment: **@unwichtich** ... No I don't use Maven. Perhaps this is the best time to learn that. :)